# Read Apache HIVE table from Informatica

Tags: informatica, apache-hive

I have need of regarding HIVE table using Informatica and then write the data after some transformations to MS SQL table.

Can anyone please let me know what is the driver / connector required to connect to Apache HIVE from Informatica. Is there any specific Informatica version from which this is supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Informatica Big Data Edition (BDE) supports Hive both as a source and target.

More information: [BDE User Guide](https://marketplace.informatica.com/mpresources/docs/IN_960_BDETrial_UserGuide_en.pdf)

Comment: Could you please provide the link pointing to the Informatica documentation in this case.

Comment: @KoushikChandra What exactly do you need to know? Here's a [BDE User Guide](https://marketplace.informatica.com/mpresources/docs/IN_960_BDETrial_UserGuide_en.pdf).

Comment: As of now I am not very clear of the requirement, but only thing I know is that the Informatica version whatever the client is using is different from BDE, so I think read will not supported .. right?

Comment: It is important to remember that you need to use Informatica Developer, not Informatica PowerCenter Designer.